# Async/Await behaviour through the stack

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm curious about how the flow of `async` works across the stack.  When reading about `async` in C#, you will continually read some version of the following:

> If the task we are awaiting has not yet completed then sign up the
>   rest of this method as the continuation of that task, and then return
>   to your caller immediately; the task will invoke the continuation when
>   it completes.

It's the **return to your caller immediately** part that confuses me.  In the below example, assuming something calls `MethodOneAsync()`, execution hits the await in `MethodOneAsync`. Does it immediately return to the method that called this?  If so, how does `MethodTwoAsync` ever get executed?  Or does it continue down the stack until it detects that it's actually blocked (ie. `DoDBWorkAsync()`) and then yield the thread?

```
public static async Task MethodOneAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork();
    await MethodTwoAsync();
}

public static async Task MethodTwoAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork();
    await MethodThreeAsync();
}

public static async Task MethodThreeAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork();
    await DoDBWorkAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part before an `await` in an `async` method is executed synchronously. That's the case for all `async` methods.

Let's assume that instead of `await DoDBWorkAsync()` we have `await Task.Delay(1000)`.

That means `MethodOneAsync` starts running, executes `DoSomeWork` and calls `MethodTwoAsync` which in turn executes `DoSomeWork` which calls `MethodThreeAsync` which again executes `DoSomeWork`.

Then it calls `Task.Delay(1000)`, gets back an uncompleted `Task` and awaits it.

That await is logically equivalent to adding a continuation and returning the task back to the caller, which is `MethodTwoAsync` which does the same and return a `Task` to the caller and so forth and so forth.

That way when the root delay `Task` completes all the continuations can run one after the other.

---

If we make your example a bit more complicated:

```
public static async Task MethodOneAsync()
{
    DoSomeWorkOne();
    await MethodTwoAsync();
    DoMoreWorkOne();
}

public static async Task MethodTwoAsync()
{
    DoSomeWorkTwo();
    await MethodThreeAsync();
    DoMoreWorkTwo();
}

public static async Task MethodThreeAsync()
{
    DoSomeWorkThree();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    DoMoreWorkThree();
}
```

It would be logically similar to doing this with continuations:

```
public static Task MethodOneAsync()
{
    DoSomeWorkOne();
    DoSomeWorkTwo();
    DoSomeWorkThree();
    return Task.Delay(1000).
        ContinueWith(_ => DoMoreWorkThree()).
        ContinueWith(_ => DoMoreWorkTwo()).
        ContinueWith(_ => DoMoreWorkOne());
}
```

Comment: Yea, your version is a lot easier to read then my version (we pretty much said the same thing) +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me do a different example so my code further down will make sense

```
public static async Task MethodOneAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork1();
    await MethodTwoAsync();
    DoOtherWork1();
}

public static async Task MethodTwoAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork2();
    await MethodThreeAsync();
    DoOtherWork2();
}

public static async Task MethodThreeAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork3();
    await DoDBWorkAsync();
    DoOtheWork3();
}
```

All async await does is turn the above code in to something similar to (but even this is a HUGE simplification) this

```
public static Task MethodOneAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork1();
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
    var resultTask = MethodTwoAsync();
    return resultTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        syncContext.Post((state) =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);
            DoOtherWork1();
        }, null);
    });
}

public static Task MethodTwoAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork2();
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
    var resultTask = MethodThreeAsync();
    return resultTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        syncContext.Post((state) =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);
            DoOtherWork2();
        }, null);
    });
}

public static Task MethodThreeAsync()
{
    DoSomeWork3();
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
    var resultTask = DoDbWorkAsync();
    return resultTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        syncContext.Post((state) =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);
            DoOtherWork3();
        }, null);
    });
}.
```

Each await just executes the next layer deeper till it is forced to return a Task, once that happens it starts doing continuations on the tasks when they complete and in that continuation it passes in a delegate representing "the rest of the function" to `SynchronizationContext.Post(` to get the code scheduled to be executed.

How it is scheduled depends on which `SynchronizationContext` you are in. In WPF and Winforms it queues it to the message pump, for the default and ASP.NET it queues it on a thread pool worker.

Answer (score 0):

It does return **after** firing the `Task` for `MethodTwoAsync` method (or continues execution, if this `Task` is immediately done), so the inner `Task` is executing into `SynchronizationContext.Current` environment.

And after this `Task` is done, the .NET state machine return the execution to the point right after the `MethodTwoAsync` firing, and process the rest of the code.

See more information at [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

[image]